# ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed while creating resource in Sendgrid

Tags: azure, powershell, sendgrid, azure-rm-template, az

I am trying to create Sendgrid resource. Couple of days before it was working fine. From Yesterday I am getting the following error. Any Solution please.

> vso[task.logissue type=error]- Resource Sendgrid.Email/accounts 'XXXXXXXXXXX' failed with message '{%0D%0A  "error": {%0D%0A
>   "code": "ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed",%0D%0A    "message": "User
>   failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: 'Something
>   went wrong. If you think this is an error please contact our support
>   team.'"%0D%0A  }%0D%0A}'

Comment: I did that. Waiting for the response. It's taking time. It's been 24 hours already. So just wanted to clarify if anyone had faced this issue

Answer (score 0):

Please be advised that the sendgrid purchase needs to be done by the Account Administrator and/or any other user with Owner RBAC role assigned to it.

Also if you have the right permission set, i would suggest you to check the account creation limit, it could be because of that also.

If this doesn't work , please go through the network trace file and check what is causing the issue and try to perform the step.
For network trace , you can do the following step and post it in your question:

- Open Internet Explorer
- Press F12 (This action will opens a window at the bottom of the main IE window)
- Select the “Network” Tab (selected by default)
- Ensure the Clear entries on navigate button is selected(button with a blue arrow pointing to the right,
  and a red X in the upper-left corner)

**Note**: By default this option is selected. When this option is de-selected it will allow sensitive information such as any usernames and 
passwords to be saved in clear text in the capture file. Microsoft will NEVER ask you to provide your password as part of troubleshooting so it
is imperative that you leave the
Clear entries on navigate option selected or you will need to manually delete the password from the trace file 
before sending the trace to us for our investigation.

- Perform the action which is causing the unexpected behavior or error message
- Once the problem is reproduced, click the Stop Capturing button (the red square icon)
- Click the Export as HAR button (floppy disk icon) to save the file

Hope it helps.